# The reference to column "USER_COUNT" is not allowed in the argument of the TOP clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help on a problem.

I have a table like that :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[USER_ACTIONS]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [USER_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ACTION_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DEVICE_ID] [tinyint] NOT NULL
    [DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
            WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                  IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                  ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I would like to keep the 10 newest records and `GROUP BY USER_ID, ACTION_ID AND DEVICE_ID`.

Here's what I tried :

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempUsers') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TempUsers

SELECT USER_ID, COUNT(USER_ID) as USER_COUNT
INTO #TempUsers 
FROM USER_ACTIONS
GROUP BY USER_ID, ACTION_ID,DEVICE_ID
HAVING COUNT(USER_ID) > 10
ORDER BY USER_COUNT

DELETE FROM USER_ACTIONS Actions
WHERE ID IN (SELECT TOP (USER_COUNT - 10) ID 
             FROM #TempUsers TMP 
             WHERE Actions.USER_ID = TMP.USER_ID 
             ORDER BY DATE ASC)
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work and I receive this message :

> The reference to column "USER_COUNT" is not allowed in the argument of the TOP clause. Only references to columns at an outer scope or standalone expressions and subqueries are allowed here.

I would like to avoid loops for performance.

If someone has an idea I will be very grateful.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you sort by date and `SELECT top 10`?

Comment: Are you sure it this the correct code, I cant find TOP clause in this query ?

Comment: Thanks for your help but I don't want the 10 newest but 10 newest for a specific user, action and device.
For example :
if I have connected 20 times I want to keep the 10 newest.
if another user connected 7 times I do nothing.
...

Comment: Yes that the correct code, here is the top clause :
DELETE FROM USER_ACTIONS Actions
WHERE ID IN (SELECT TOP (USER_COUNT - 10) ID FROM #TempUsers TMP WHERE Actions.USER_ID = TMP.USER_ID ORDER BY DATE ASC )

Comment: Ah, re-read your comment. Still seems like your code is making more difficult than it needs to be. Think you could provide a quick sample table and output to clear it up a bit?

Comment: The way I'm reading it, which sounds like it isn't correct, would be solved by `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM table WHERE USER_ID = # AND ACTION_ID = # AND DEVICE_ID = # ORDER BY DATE ASC`
Sounds like I'm missing something though, are you trying to consider only the users that have at least 10 entries?

Comment: slap that in a `NOT IN()`, `DELETE` those rows, and you're good to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `ROW_NUMBER()` and delete where it is higher than 10 to remove the oldest rows and leave the 10 newest for each combination

```
DELETE  t
FROM    (   SELECT  *, 
                    RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() 
                                    OVER(PARTITION BY USER_ID, ACTION_ID,DEVICE_ID 
                                        ORDER BY DATE DESC) 
            FROM    USER_ACTIONS
        ) AS t
WHERE   t.RowNumber > 10;
```

Comment: It's weird but when I add an index on USER_ID to try to improve perfomance the execution time is two times larger than without the index.
Just for information, I have only 20 Action_Id and 8 Device_Id
Have I miss something on that? 

Thanks a lot

Comment: When you have an index in place you have to delete from both the clustered index and the non clustered index. So although you might speed up identifying the rows to delete, you sacrifice time when you actually have to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT 
  *
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.USER_ID,a.ACTION_ID,a.DEVICE_ID ORDER BY a.DATE DESC) rn
INTO #tmp
FROM USER_ACTIONS a

SELECT
  t.USER_ID,
  t.ACTION_ID,
  t.DEVICE_ID
  t.DATE
FROM #tmp t
WHERE t.rn <= 10
```